# 80x86 assembly code not returning from function and displaying output

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm

The goal of the program is to calculate a GCD of two numbers using a recursive function defined by this pseudo code

```
unsigned int gcd ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b ) {
if ( a > b )
        return gcd ( a - b, b ) ;

if ( a < b )
        return gcd ( a, b - a ) ;

    return a ;
}
```

Here is the (undoubtedly poor) assembly code I'm having issues with.

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h
.STACK 4096

.DATA
a DWORD   ?
b DWORD   ?
prompt1 BYTE    "a: ", 0
prompt2 BYTE    "b:", 0
string  BYTE    20 DUP (?)
resultLbl BYTE  "gcd:", 0
result  BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0


.CODE
_MainProc PROC
        input   prompt1, string, 20      
        atod    string          
        mov     a, eax    

        input   prompt2, string, 20      
        atod    string
        mov     b, eax

        push    b         
        push    a         
        call    _gcd           
        add     esp, 8          

        dtoa    result, eax     
        output  resultLbl, result  

        mov     eax, 0  
        ret
_MainProc ENDP


_gcd   PROC
        push    ebp             
        mov     ebp, esp       
        push    ebx           
        push eax

        mov     eax, [ebp+8]   
        mov     ebx, [ebp+12]  

        cmp     eax, ebx
        jg      loop1
        cmp     eax, ebx
        jl      loop2

        pop     ebx             
        pop     ebp             
        ret   

loop1:
        push    ebx
        sub     eax, ebx
        push    eax
        call    _gcd

loop2:             
        sub     ebx, eax
        push    ebx
        push    eax
        output  did2, result
        call    _gcd




_gcd   ENDP

END
```

By creating some outputs in the loops to display a message when they occur I can tell that the program is calculating the GCD correctly however as soon as both values are equal and "ret" is hit inside of _gcd the program terminates. What do I need to change so the GCD value is returned and displayed correctly?

Comment: Multiple problems. For example, your `return a ;` is just `return`. Also, your `loop1` is falling through into `loop2` so that is not a `return` at all. You forgot to restore the stack too. PS: don't call things `loop` if they are not loops...

Comment: Your C code has three returns but your assembly code only has one.

Comment: you mess up your stack. you push a lot of values before you (several times) call _gcd, and only remove the once (in main). the "loop" parts do not return, they just fallthru, and don't cleanup anything